# New to svelte and javascript, web app for learning solfege

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am new to JavaScript and Svelte. For a school project, I want to create a web application to learn the basics of solfeggio, but I have found a way to do it, but I feel that it's not the right way at all

Right now I have an array that represents my sheet music staff, of another array of int that represents my lines, and i update like this code snippet:

````
onMount(()
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
            rand();
            portee[wch_line].main[pos] = 1;
            portee[wch_line].main[pos + 1] = 0;
            if (pos === 0) {
                reset();
            }
            pos -= 1;
        }, 10);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    });```
````

I shift my 1 on my array from 0, and then I display the note at the location of the 1, otherwise I display a "-" which visually represents my line. Here is the link to my git if you want to take a look: https://github.com/BaptisteKELAGOPIAN/SolfegeLearning. But as I said, it's slow at times, but most of all I don't want to continue like this when I feel there is a better way to do all of this. If you have any leads, it would be great, thank you.

Comment: If you want visuals, I would recommend looking into SVGs. What exactly should happen there, a line of staff paper scrolling by?

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, i'm going take a look, i would like some static lines, et some music notes move on them (sorry for me english)